# Return State ID from Containing County Event

Tags: json, d3.js, topojson

I have a topojson map that has both county and state data in json format. There are no actual names for the states, but the states do each have a unique id. I would like to find a way to return the id of a state if the user clicks on one of its containing counties.

The trouble is I cannot seem to be able to access the state ids in the json when I set up my click event listener. I have sliced and diced the json data every which way, but I keep going in circles. Is it possible to have asymmetric information within the json file? I feel like the state ids are in a black box when working with the containing counties.

Let me know if anything comes to mind. I have a fully functional minimalist example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/826071f2c0757f07101defba62c8c38e), where I am trying to return a console log of the state id based on user click.

**Note:** I would prefer to avoid point in polygon solutions for complexity reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your `json` file ships with [FIPS county code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code). That means that first two digits of county code are in fact the [state code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standard_state_code). So `Math.floor(county.id / 1000)` is what you‘re looking for in the end.

Comment: I knew there was a clever person out there who would know what to do here! I'm trying it out now